# Moving a cakePHP3 app to iPage server

Tags: .htaccess, cakephp, mod-rewrite, server

I have been developing my own personal CakePHP3 application which works completely fine when I run it from my local computer. When I upload the application to my web host I get a 500 internal server error when I try to open my application. It can be found at http://www.tommorisonwebdesign.com/trustlesslending.

My problem is I do not get such a message when I run the application locally on my Macbook. I can see the app no problem. I have looked around other questions and couldn't find an answer. Anyone else had a similar problem? I am hosting the app in a subdirectory.

Below is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /
   RewriteRule    ^$ /webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) /webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I just checked the error log and I am getting this error message when I load my app: 
20151012T152432: tommorisonwebdesign.com/trustlesslending/webroot/index.php 
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /hermes/bosoraweb152/b1685/ipg.tommorisonwebdesignc/trustlesslending/config/bootstrap.php on line 107

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Morison It is hard from here to find out what is the problem. But follow these few guidelines first, if you face problem after this post a comment.

1) First important thing is, Permissions of folders may not be correct. If CakePHP app is Group Writable i.e. 777 then webserver gives 500 error for safety

2)  Best practice is please delete cache if you move your application from one place to another. Delete the content of your tmp folder and move it to live server from your local system

3) Try to enable debugging to see flow for testing purpose using Configure::write('debug',2);

4) Lot of information you can find /var/log/apache2/error.log, if you get errors ( i didnot know your environment,this path is in linux). Check that file

5) Be aware that, local and production server databases have different database connections details,check them whether you are missing any Database Connection.

6) Your.htaccess looks good, but any way check here for correct syntax, http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/installation/url-rewriting.html

7) My best guess is, your live server may not have enabled the mod_rewrite  (if so, .htaccess with RewriteBase will cause trouble

Also,You can try to comment the .htaccess and see if it runs fine in the server and then re-enable the configurations one at a time to try to figure things out.

Comment: What I see in my error log is that my ROOT paths are still set to my dev server. Where would I be able to change that path?

Comment: Can you edit your question and put the error log file output thier?

Comment: Tom, thank you for the error log. I think you are running PHP < 5.4. CakePHP 3 requires at least PHP 5.4.16 to run correctly. Can you check using the  [ echo phpinfo() ], Be careful, php -v command line command doesnot show proper version number for some reason, i didnot know. But use phpinfo in some test file.

Comment: I tried opening the php.info file outside my Application rote and get the same error. It's a problem with my .htaccess.

Comment: Ha :) Tom, i asked you to open the phpinfo(), to let me know what version of php you are using. Please check my earlier comment.I checked your .htaccess file (CakePHP app directory file), i am only thinking about, "RewriteBase /", is your app is at the "root /" folder or your app has any path?

Comment: My apoligies. I did some debugging on my own and found it is impossible to use the CakePHP framework on iPage because intl.so is not enabled. I am hosting my app now on the free OpenShift server from redhat.

Answer (score 0):

@Tom Morison It is tough from here to search out out what's the problem. But follow these few tips initial, if you face downside after this post a comment.

1st necessary issue is, Permissions of folders may not be correct. If CakePHP app is Group Writable i.e. 777 then webserver provides five hundred error for safety

Best observe is please delete cache if you move your application from one place to another. Delete the content of your tmp folder and move it to measure server from your native system Try to enable debugging to determine flow for testing purpose using Configure::write('debug',2);

Be aware that, local and production server databases have totally different database connections details,check them whether or not you're missing any Database Connection.

Your .htaccess looks sensible, however any way check here for correct syntax
[ipage coupon](http://www.couponvsoffer.com/coupons/ipage-coupon-for-cheap-hosting-plan-grab-it-soon/)